# Core Data Custom Policy Migration - Creating Relationships

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a simple example project where I have "Store" that has a few attributes "apples", "oranges", "pineapples" of type Int 16. I am trying to do a custom heavyweight migration to create a new "Item" entity that has a name and count. I am able to migrate successfully using a mapping model and a custom policy to migrate the old values to the new item entity.

```
class ItemsMapping: NSEntityMigrationPolicy {

override func createDestinationInstances(forSource sInstance: NSManagedObject, in mapping: NSEntityMapping, manager: NSMigrationManager) throws {
    if sInstance.entity.name == "Store" {
        if let apples = sInstance.primitiveValue(forKey: "apples") as? Int16 {
            let item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Item", into: manager.destinationContext)
            item.setValue("Apples", forKey: "name")
            item.setValue(apples, forKey: "count")
        }
        
        if let oranges = sInstance.primitiveValue(forKey: "oranges") as? Int16 {
            let item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Item", into: manager.destinationContext)
            item.setValue("Oranges", forKey: "name")
            item.setValue(oranges, forKey: "count")
        }
        
        if let pineapples = sInstance.primitiveValue(forKey: "pineapples") as? Int16 {
            let item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Item", into: manager.destinationContext)
            item.setValue("Pineapples", forKey: "name")
            item.setValue(pineapples, forKey: "count")
        }
    }
}

override func createRelationships(forDestination dInstance: NSManagedObject, in mapping: NSEntityMapping, manager: NSMigrationManager) throws {
    print("test")
}
```

The only problem is that the Store object needs to have a one-to-many relationship with Item and I couldn't find any good examples online about creating relationships with heavyweight migration.

Here's the initial data model:

[image: v1 of the data model]

and the new data model(v2):

[image]

[image]

Finally, here is my mapping model:
[image]

Without the relationships, my createDestinationInstances override works as expected, but I need to create a relationship with the Store object and I couldn't find any good resources online.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The function names in `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` can be a little confusing.

In `createDestinationInstances(...)`, you take an existing managed object and create the new managed object that replaces it after migration. You're working on the `Store` entity, so you create a new `Store` to replace the old one. Don't create any other managed objects here. After you create the new `Store`,

- Set its `name` to match the one from the `sInstance` argument
- Call `manager.associate(...)` to tell the manager that the new `Store` is the replacement for the old one. (Very very important for the steps below to work).

The `items` relationship is nil for now. That's the next step.

In `createRelationships(...)`, the `dInstance` argument is a new post-migration `Store` you created above. This is where you create the new `Item` instances for the it. You do that like this:

1. Look up the original pre-migration `Store` by calling `manager.sourceInstnaces(...)`. That gives you an array, but there should only be one object in it.
2. Create your new `Item` objects. This is pretty much the same as you're doing this in your question except you'll be looking at the pre-migration `Store` you looked up in step 1 to decide what `Item`s to create.
3. Create the relationship between the new store (`dInstance` here) and the new items you created in step 2.

It's a bit complicated, but that's how it should work.